# Would stalked hair help a tunneling humanoid?

Tags: fantasy-races, underground, hair

Many mammals that dig and live in underground tunnels have short/no hair, so as to avoid the hair being bent backwards if they need to reverse out of their tunnel. However, I'd like my tunneling humanoid species to have longer hair

One potential solution I'm considering is, rather than having hair directly on the head, having many flexible stalks from which the hairs grow out of. These stalks contain the entire follicle, and can bend to lie in any direction against the scalp. They also have limited musculature at a similar strength to human goosebumps

[image: diagram]

Would this structure help them avoid hair-related issues when reversing down their tunnels?

Comment: Can you add a sketch of what you are describing with words?

Comment: @L.Dutch I've added a diagram

Comment: This is as good a solution as any, but is there evidence that burrowing animals have short hair simply because it makes it difficult to back out of a tight tunnel? If we can basically describe evolution as "the ascendance of problem solving," it's more likely that the discomfort of rubbing fur the wrong way is overcome by digging a modestly bigger hole.

Comment: This is not a problem. I would be happy to believe the creature has a skin or follicle type that solves this problem, without bothering to explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't feel that this would work, as now instead of the hair being bent and damaged at the base, the follicle is going to be bent and damaged, leading to bleeding, infection and death.

A simple behavioural solution might be plaiting! Braided hair is forced to lie flat against itself, mitigating many of the issues of longer hair.  Plaiting seems like a complex behaviour, but it is well within what evolution is capable of doing as instinctive behaviour.